# How to filter out array data based on some outer conditions in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

```
const arr=['A','B'];
arr.filter(()=>{
if(type==all){return full array}
else{return arr[1]}
)
```

What I want is whenever the type is all return complete array but for rest of the condition return only the element at index 1.

Comment: Nothing is shared code contains a `type` property. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter only when `type` is other than `all`, otherwise return the original data:

**Demo:**

```js
const arr = [{type: "A", value: "A"}, {type: "B", value: "B"}]
let type = ""

const filterArr = () => {
  if (type === "all") {
    return arr // Don't filter
  }
  return arr.filter(item => item.type === type) // Filter when type is other than "all"
}

type = "all"
console.log(filterArr())

type = "B"
console.log(filterArr())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return array directly by using conditional operators

Try:-

```
const arr=['A','B'];
return type === all ? arr : arr[1]
```

Or you can use filter like below:-

```
const arr=['A','B'];
const filteredArray = arr.filter((value, index) => type === all || index === 1);
```

Comment: can you help me how can i use filter function here